# USB : disable and reenable device on linux

Tags: linux, usb

I have an USB device that sometimes hangs. Since it is really a pain to unplug/plug it (cables under desk, behind things...), is there a way to virtually unplug/plug the device ? For example by shutting down its power then bring it back again ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with the `USBDEVFS_RESET` ioctl.

If your system doesn't come with a `usbreset` utility as part of `usbutils`, you can compile the one from https://github.com/gregkh/usbutils/blob/master/usbreset.c with just `cc usbreset.c -o usbreset`.

On some devices (like my router) you'll have to reset the hub it's connected to instead of the device for it to have effect.

```
# ./usbreset
Usage:
  usbreset PPPP:VVVV - reset by product and vendor id
  usbreset BBB/DDD   - reset by bus and device number
  usbreset "Product" - reset by product name

Devices:
  Number 001/004  ID 062a:4101  2.4G Keyboard Mouse
  Number 001/006  ID 03f0:e111  DeskJet 2130 series
  Number 001/002  ID 05e3:0608  USB2.0 Hub
  Number 001/005  ID 248a:8514  Wireless Receiver
  Number 001/003  ID 05e3:0608  USB2.0 Hub
$ ./a.out 062a:4101
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted `USBDEVFS_RESET` solution is not as good as replugging (based on the kernel messages). Better use the "port" interface, e.g.:

```
echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2.1/port/disable
```

See more on this on my [other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/767364/9417).